# Convert document to PDF

Tags: php, xml, pdf, soap, pdf-generation

I have a **stranger** document that I don't know which extension it is, and I need to convert it into a **PDF**, so the idea is to get that content dynamically, then we save it in server as a **PDF**

My try :

```
$responce = $this->getDocumentContent();//this function returns me the $responce content bellow. 
$documentFolder = $this->getDirectory().'/document/'; //var/www/project/document/
$documentFullPath = $this->getDirectory().'/document/file1.pdf';
$this->_io->mkdir($documentFolder, 0775);//create folder var/www/project/document
$document = fopen($documentFullPath, "w+");//create pdf file var/www/project/document/file1.pdf
fwrite($document, $responce);
fclose($document);
```

Now with this code, I create well the `file1.pdf` in `var/www/project/document/file1.pdf` but it is empty !, there is no content, the `file1.pdf` weight is not `0` but `163.2 Ko` but I see anything. I don't know where is the issue.

`$responce =`

```
string(163146) "%PDF-1.4
%????
1 0 obj
<< 
/Type /Catalog 
/Pages 2 0 R 
/Metadata 63 0 R 
>> 
endobj
2 0 obj
<< 
/Type /Pages 
/Kids [ 01 0 R 8 0 R ] 
/Count 2 
/MediaBox [ 0 0 618 003 ] 
>> 
endobj
3 0 obj
<< 
/ModDate (D:20190907120701+02'00')
/CreationDate (D:20130904150701+02'00')
/Title (F:/Data/Composer/0510.IN.PDF)
/Subject (NONE)
/Author (User: Windows XP/ User)
/Creator (PDF/PReS Version: 6.1.1       )
/Producer ([ClibPDF Library 2.02-r1-2] Windows XP)
>> 
endobj
5 0 obj
<< 
/Type /Page 
/Parent 2 0 R 
/Resources << /Font << /Fcpdf0 30 0 R >> /XObject << /6p 8 0 R >> /ProcSet 7 0 R >> 
/MediaBox [ 0 0 595 842 ] 
/CropBox [ 0 0 595 842 ] 
/Rotate 0 
/Contents 6 0 R 
>> 
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Length 246 /Filter [ /FlateDecode ] >> 
stream
x??QMk?@?'1?bia=?!?L6I7?V??AB??AQ(???_:?T?"$;<vf??7?I??c?(?(?????F??4?E?<L?ku????xs???w*??
??FGD?AlY?{,???E??-A????u?o?/^^O%|??>???\?T?Y
??iS??5q?t?C2I??q???c>?V?z?8:??C??#???p/?\???0F)k#?1???U?`Sa?????.???PyoY
endstream
endobj
7 0 obj
[ 
/PDF /Text /ImageC 
]
endobj
8 0 obj
<< /Type /XObject /BBox [ 0 0 595 842 ] /Filter /FlateDecode /FormType 1 
/Length 17871 /Matrix [ 1 0 0 1 0 0 ] /Resources << /ColorSpace << /CS0 27 0 R /CS1 26 0 R /CS10 27 0 R /CS11 26 0 R /CS12 27 0 R /CS13 26 0 R 
/CS14 29 0 R /CS15 28 0 R /CS16 29 0 R /CS17 28 0 R /CS18 29 0 R 
/CS19 28 0 R /CS2 27 0 R /CS20 29 0 R /CS21 28 0 R /CS22 29 0 R 
/CS23 28 0 R /CS24 29 0 R /CS25 28 0 R /CS26 29 0 R /CS27 28 0 R 
/CS28 29 0 R /CS29 28 0 R /CS3 26 0 R /CS30 29 0 R /CS31 28 0 R 
/CS32 29 0 R /CS33 28 0 R /CS34 29 0 R /CS35 28 0 R /CS36 29 0 R 
/CS37 28 0 R /CS4 27 0 R /CS5 26 0 R /CS6 27 0 R /CS7 26 0 R /CS8 27 0 R 
/CS9 26 0 R >> 
/ExtGState << /GS6 25 0 R >> /Font << /TT24 21 0 R /TT25 17 0 R /TT26 13 0 R /TT27 9 0 R >> 
/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text ] >> 
/Subtype /Form >> 
stream
x??}i?$????K?l2?@?:gu?F??????r$?im?1k???????E???????;?O???=????????????7?????o????oO??????}???O??uz?????z?O????p=M???4n~??w/??;|????OGw>???>???9???cSn'????b????5????????w??\????????_~????t?w8N??9??~?f}??qxy??????o???????M??????'?Or4|?O????|??y??o???=?=
?y?p??1vx?)??7???on????.??w?????-??K??|y:?w}d??????:???>uv??:?.???y???6?nm{????E0\??????n?????B??ra*??x?t?K^???'??7?i?8???]?p?D}??T??-?lcN???_????Q7h??n??s???n==?
??!?
?@~s??F8??G?0?K??e??ul?3n???g??????6?0?a???$??L?j?W??9~U??{?G?U??9fO?????rL?K[Z??E?!????}T|?yr/?}?+?O???6??um????a??E^?K??P??U:??+?pL??N?Q????^\?{a???[??k?N?t/????K{?Ek_???
???t??U#??\O;??????????5??~???????
K??O??9?????</?(?*7????u?n?xa?4??rbd??^N?^z??]?7?T????r?f????|Y?ij?mC'u3???o?4On?r???Kd+
?.??t?6??(?fa+5?$??5?}??,??ZB?Fe??E5W(??.J7??yk1??u?F\?o:^???hK???vNH?]?K???r?????U??H?d?????
X???[e3 7???????qz?K?7c1>?
??o?y??Q????<?8???G4??????^?u?&??&?r???'?o??LN?_??  l??1an+G9&?m?1~?'?e?<?
!??o?-??????J?r???x??`?/o?-??=????y?,????R?0y?? ??.rz|3?GhmS? U?!t????A?Oi????}?6??ct5?i???|?.?&?\??]???2?n?\?<7? ?>?4??"X1M?j??>H??}???iX??~???^?????q?????)
??;2?????'??bS????d???N?/L???K?\n?=n~&F?????fd;m?4?c????Xf??'9?D?s????`4,Mg?f????F??n?~-?????+@l??1??z?N�????l??$??+J?N6? ???}:j8Q?????$L?|C?&???^ch?70??C(?????&??????8B?L.??A??D0]?5?+?)??d?X?>??0C??|?A?&?Z???H??J?0?(m?Rr?Y???*???3?o???{??c?[???E?5 ????q?k??:V;T4?+T??>*B(???|I??}?T??7?N??�?g?W?'??U?'2v`?   4????O?)??x?*r?,?b^7??/3??y(M?Nnnd??i??????:?,?|??EYtx/]?g?!?sgi-{?i<?"????????`??4?[�??h?s*???L?,@??8???G?-(%???=?o/A?????!?????_"??%????_??y???a?%???G4?r?|?M??@z=?~???&v?J?]?<?tQ?
??n?�j?GHh[???&J??!?p?l?b?_w?\ ?#?dXb??a}?l??????S5"D~?5??w??n?.v?C?^?E??;?]????#????a???Z>Tb?;Et U?<?; pl?k???b+?m??`????Is?$3<??6??K?w??
rz???e??i@?5$;-??q4Z"????(_5??E??L?ayv
y?s?M?????R?p?T8?-B?o??i?_?~\??????t??]7a?? K~9!?
?_y.H??8??5z?%?B?w?Vy?}`!h1??? ?v?u?i????????r?&?t?"??%Om??:???a3Y??j?P7?N???(?zu???6I$Z/?"??v^???  mp??/?
h?I?'?V?9'Iexj}?z?t?S?*Y?m3i?J?H??Q???3???dUd?fk???}m????k???!H?%I>??????"???[\|*V??~J??????i-??Z??H??ayb????Ca?i^cP??i???r????????L??4??#??RH???(?Jb??[f??N?1;???&.
???Q???~~???e;?&[?  ???0>wRI???s??c%"r???x??n?r}?b??j?h?MO???? q??'?@v$?????g?Xd?h?Pl:?M?\???9B5�?G?j??IE?J?~??????M ??A?<?[???/P7n??Q??0ej?_c?J?u??+J?xl???f?)?0?  K?*??W519??uy??r6}??    ?N???s?)?X???????2-?j??b\????M{?f?????E?|?-???x+?zN?f�3?)^k'?qR????zevW?,d?V??????{6!?? ??@j?y?,?BZQ????!?eW???M??
U???D
Q)vWL?N?&??T?q_C?j??@?p??????V????It?.??[??-g<]i?.T�?6%|?W??n?3?x?xx??,???b&?e??Q]???Z?&l"?L???S??N ??F???+W??y??�%??Q-oc????d?S?6???/ ?_??&?t???8p??U??�Z?
?�+^???J???? r  ?k??wIB?o?P?Z?]?X???c??6N??I&w?????i"I\??v2Jr?[?(??4?}?q???t?4??!?????B??<o???Q[??Q??A???mG???Q?<???f?P??
?????????Lp1??6F    ?L;??J???????/????l?i??u?1??rw?
??c????????G??W??R?o?|?fz EA????JA?Z?
???0?b?EHP?p??7=?]g>d'?mk?3?5M|?E?8?_?T.?,???M?,dnP?L???hs=?;&???????(L?????4_??a?R^?LX??o?v+????7???????(?P??)b??A$?f??#?GF1S??????8b??RM.>?_?!Ab?`?Fs???+?#?HV??iM44?;u<C?????M]H?]?XQ1?f?JG????n1
?R???8?????m?<?}D???)?W3?�??k???T???SI???G??G ?hS*???bD%?=p?f2?SO?K?5??9?^8??$??v??5?7.4k%_???}?Li?h?MHqf?2q?Rj-???,'?k?o?Y_zk?W??
H?QTs>c???fx?g???D|?H?d???V?]96?3?V?1?(????u?e,?B?+ ECl7D???b?C74???l?Bt
```

Answer (score 1):

The PDF mentions it actually:

```
/Producer ([ClibPDF Library 2.02-r1-2] Windows XP)
```

ClibPDF support for PHP was moved into PECL a long time ago (with PHP 5.1). The extension was not object oriented, so here is some additional wrapper around it.

Alternatives are [Haru](https://php.net/manual/en/book.haru.php), [PDFlib](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php), or one of the available PHP based libraries.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation, have you some idea or example to how to use it, I tried `PDF_open_file` , `PDF_pcos_get_stream ` but it doesn't work, he told me that the function doesn't exist, Do i have to import some library ?