# convert stream to PDF

Tags: php, xml, pdf, soap, stream

I have a stream document I think and I need to convert it into a **PDF**.

The idea is to save that stream it in server as a **PDF**

My code :

```
$responce = $this->getDocumentContent();//this function returns me the $responce content bellow. 
$documentFolder = $this->getDirectory().'/document/'; //var/www/project/document/
$documentFullPath = $this->getDirectory().'/document/file1.pdf';
$this->_io->mkdir($documentFolder, 0775);//create folder var/www/project/document
$document = fopen($documentFullPath, "w+");//create pdf file var/www/project/document/file1.pdf
fwrite($document, $responce);
fclose($document);
```

Now with this code, I create well the `file1.pdf` in `var/www/project/document/file1.pdf` but it is empty !, there is no content, the `file1.pdf` weight is not `0` but `163.2 Ko` but I see anything. I don't know where is the issue.

`$responce =`

```
string(163146) "%PDF-1.4
%????
1 0 obj
<< 
/Type /Catalog 
/Pages 2 0 R 
/Metadata 63 0 R 
>> 
endobj
2 0 obj
<< 
/Type /Pages 
/Kids [ 01 0 R 8 0 R ] 
/Count 2 
/MediaBox [ 0 0 618 003 ] 
>> 
endobj
3 0 obj
<< 
/ModDate (D:20190907120701+02'00')
/CreationDate (D:20130904150701+02'00')
/Title (F:/Data/Composer/0510.IN.PDF)
/Subject (NONE)
/Author (User: Windows XP/ User)
/Creator (PDF/PReS Version: 6.1.1       )
/Producer ([ClibPDF Library 2.02-r1-2] Windows XP)
>> 
endobj
5 0 obj
<< 
/Type /Page 
/Parent 2 0 R 
/Resources << /Font << /Fcpdf0 30 0 R >> /XObject << /6p 8 0 R >> /ProcSet 7 0 R >> 
/MediaBox [ 0 0 595 842 ] 
/CropBox [ 0 0 595 842 ] 
/Rotate 0 
/Contents 6 0 R 
>> 
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Length 246 /Filter [ /FlateDecode ] >> 
stream
x??QMk?@?'1?bia=?!?L6I7?V??AB??AQ(???_:?T?"$;<vf??7?I??c?(?(?????F??4?E?<L?ku????xs???w*??
??FGD?AlY?{,???E??-A????u?o?/^^O%|??>???\?T?Y
??iS??5q?t?C2I??q???c>?V?z?8:??C??#???p/?\???0F)k#?1???U?`Sa?????.???PyoY
endstream
endobj
7 0 obj
[ 
/PDF /Text /ImageC 
]
endobj
8 0 obj
<< /Type /XObject /BBox [ 0 0 595 842 ] /Filter /FlateDecode /FormType 1 
/Length 17871 /Matrix [ 1 0 0 1 0 0 ] /Resources << /ColorSpace << /CS0 27 0 R /CS1 26 0 R /CS10 27 0 R /CS11 26 0 R /CS12 27 0 R /CS13 26 0 R 
/CS14 29 0 R /CS15 28 0 R /CS16 29 0 R /CS17 28 0 R /CS18 29 0 R 
/CS19 28 0 R /CS2 27 0 R /CS20 29 0 R /CS21 28 0 R /CS22 29 0 R 
/CS23 28 0 R /CS24 29 0 R /CS25 28 0 R /CS26 29 0 R /CS27 28 0 R 
/CS28 29 0 R /CS29 28 0 R /CS3 26 0 R /CS30 29 0 R /CS31 28 0 R 
/CS32 29 0 R /CS33 28 0 R /CS34 29 0 R /CS35 28 0 R /CS36 29 0 R 
/CS37 28 0 R /CS4 27 0 R /CS5 26 0 R /CS6 27 0 R /CS7 26 0 R /CS8 27 0 R 
/CS9 26 0 R >> 
/ExtGState << /GS6 25 0 R >> /Font << /TT24 21 0 R /TT25 17 0 R /TT26 13 0 R /TT27 9 0 R >> 
/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text ] >> 
/Subtype /Form >> 
stream
x??}i?$????K?l2?@?:gu?F??????r$?im?1k???????E???????;?O???=????????????7?????o????oO??????}???O??uz?????z?O????p=M???4n~??w/??;|????OGw>???>???9???cSn'????b????5????????w??\????????_~????t?w8N??9??~?f}??qxy??????o???????M??????'?Or4|?O????|??y??o???=?=
?y?p??1vx?)??7???on????.??w?????-??K??|y:?w}d??????:???>uv??:?.???y???6?nm{????E0\??????n?????B??ra*??x?t?K^???'??7?i?8???]?p?D}??T??-?lcN???_????Q7h??n??s???n==?
??!?
?@~s??F8??G?0?K??e??ul?3n???g??????6?0?a???$??L?j?W??9~U??{?G?U??9fO?????rL?K[Z??E?!????}T|?yr/?}?+?O???6??um????a??E^?K??P??U:??+?pL??N?Q????^\?{a???[??k?N?t/????K{?Ek_???
???t??U#??\O;??????????5??~???????
K??O??9?????</?(?*7????u?n?xa?4??rbd??^N?^z??]?7?T????r?f????|Y?ij?
```

`...`

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840516/convert-document-to-pdf Please do not create such duplicates, but follow up on issues like this within your original question, thank you.

Comment: as I didn't have an answer, I thought my question was not clear to everyone, that's why I created a new

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert document to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840516/convert-document-to-pdf)